# Where has "Browser Mode" gone from Internet Explorer 11 developer tools?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-dev

IE10's Browser Mode setting under Developer Tools seemed to be extremely useful. I cannot find it in IE 11. Does the option still exist? If so, where?

Comment: It is possible to bring them back by editing registry:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871124/how-to-bring-back-browser-mode-in-ie11/17934862#17934862

Comment: A shame that they removed one of the more useful functions IE had over other browsers. Yet another reason to go with a non-IE browser - particularly with regards to development. Thank you so much for all the responses. It's very hard to pick a winner but I've gone for the selected answer based on community votes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's gone. There's an underwhelming **Emulation** tab, but the ability to emulate old IE versions has been removed.

[image: 1]

As [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255001(v=vs.85).aspx) states, "**If you need to test webpages in older versions of IE**, check out [Modern.ie](http://www.modern.ie) for testing tools, including virtual machines that run older versions of IE in appropriate versions of Windows."

Comment: I'd suggest downgrading back to IE10: http://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Internet-Explorer-11-for-Windows-7

Comment: @wings this option is not showing in my PC http://screenpresso.com/=FDyO I upgraded from Win 7 to 8.1

Answer (score 10):

In the latest update to Windows 8.1 the IE 11 F12 developer tools you can set the document mode to; 5, 7, 8, 9, 10 or Edge (11) mode from the emulator tool. The feature wasn't in earlier builds.

Answer (score 2):

For some users (such as myself - lucky me) the Browser Mode and the User agent string dropdowns are both blank. This is really annoying as I do need to constantly test in various modes (I do developer support so this is crucial to me.

Thus far, the best answer I could find was on [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/document-mode-and-user-agent-string-dropdowns/cd34d5f8-7839-4083-af55-05d49ba85190?rtAction=1387560713451) ... the suggestion there was to create a new user profile... Others said that worked but in my opinion, this is as much overkill amputating your leg to address an ingrowing toenail.

I just wanted to throw this out there in case others find this post (as I did) while looking for the answer to why is this blank)

Answer (score 1):

It has gone ([at least, gone for now](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11_pr-windows8_1_pr/ie-11-compatibility-browser-mode/79c23971-36cb-4520-93f1-3e4c1c51e389)). In the future they may bring it back but until then, you have 2 options

This can be done via a registry hack as shown here (as per comments in OP by eug1111)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871124/how-to-bring-back-browser-mode-in-ie11/17934862#17934862

[image]

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Toolbar\WebBrowser]
>   "ITBar7Layout"=hex:13,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,30,00,00,00,10,00,00,00,\
>   15,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,07,00,00,5e,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
>   00,00,00,69,e3,6f,1a,8c,f2,d9,4a,a3,e6,2b,cb,50,80,7c,f1

Also, Microsoft Expression 4 SuperPreview supports IE 6 - 9 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2445851?Browser=Internet+Explorer&Version=11)